# table covers text block in Jasper

Tags: jasper-reports

I can't put the text block on page footer because it is unique info for exactly page. How to stop the table before text block and continue on next page?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdQTy.png)

i have tried a lot of options but it doesn't work